# add string to the beginning of a text file without new line

Tags: r, bash, cat

So I am trying to import some massive tab separated `txt` file (200 MB) into `R` for statistical analysis. Unfortunately, the file format is inconsistent with the number of columns/rows. The first row contains the header names for all but the first two columns.

example:

```
header3 header4 header5

column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
```

I can repair the file after reading it into `R`, but the more elegant way would be to insert `header1 header2` into the file.
I tried:

```
cat file_with_missing_headers main_file > new_file
```

This results in a new line between the two. Is there a way to suppress the new line?
Or maybe another tool ?

Comment: you could do `read.tables`, skipping the first row, and then use `readLines` to get the first row and use the info to give your data frame columns their names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution 1

```
$ { echo -n "header1 header2 "; cat file; } >newfile
```

The `-n` suppresses the unwanted newline.

#### Solution 2

Use `sed`:

```
$ sed '1s/^/header1 header2 /' file >newfile
```

Because of the `1`, this runs a substitution against the first line (and only the first line) of `file`.  The caret `^` matches the start of the first line.  The headers are substituted in at the beginning of the line and the rest of the file is left unchanged.

Comment: Solution 1 did the job. I was not aware of the use of braces and ; in the shell. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In R, you can ignore the first line and then create a new set of names. For example,  use

```
setNames(read.table(fileName, skip = 1), paste0("header", 1:5))
```

will read the file and set the new column names all at once. Note that the default delimiter for `read.table` is `sep = ""`, so if it's a csv file you'll need to change that to `sep = ","`.

Then when you're done you can write the new data set to the same file with `write.table`, and you won't need to worry about this the next time you use the data.

Comment: I didnt try this out, yet, but still thanks for pointing out new options of read.table(). Might become useful in the future.